# Why nodeselector in Kubernetes is key-value pair?

Tags: kubernetes

While reading nodeselector ([link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#:%7E:text=nodeSelector)), I was bewildered why node selector is a key-value pair. It would have been simple if just provide an identifier. For example instead of following

```
kubectl label nodes node.xyz disktype=ssd
```

We could use

```
kubectl label nodes node.xyz ssdDisk
```

What is the reason for giving nodeselector as key value pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: because that's what the engineers who created it thought. :)

You can look at the source code. There is `nodeSelector` defined as a key-value map.
By the way, the `labels` are also defined in the same way, so that one can match the other.
Due to the fact that node selector is a key-value map - you can use a lot of them while maintaining order.

---

Here you have a [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/api/core/v1/types.go) to the code where nodeselector has been defined. You may be interested in these code snippets:

```
type NodeSelector struct {
//Required. A list of node selector terms. The terms are ORed.
NodeSelectorTerms []NodeSelectorTerm `json:"nodeSelectorTerms" protobuf:"bytes,1,rep,name=nodeSelectorTerms"`
}
```

```
type NodeSelectorTerm struct {
    // A list of node selector requirements by node's labels.
    // +optional
    MatchExpressions []NodeSelectorRequirement `json:"matchExpressions,omitempty" protobuf:"bytes,1,rep,name=matchExpressions"`
    // A list of node selector requirements by node's fields.
    // +optional
    MatchFields []NodeSelectorRequirement `json:"matchFields,omitempty" protobuf:"bytes,2,rep,name=matchFields"`
}
```

```
type NodeSelectorRequirement struct {
    // The label key that the selector applies to.
    Key string `json:"key" protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=key"`
    // Represents a key's relationship to a set of values.
    // Valid operators are In, NotIn, Exists, DoesNotExist. Gt, and Lt.
    Operator NodeSelectorOperator `json:"operator" protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=operator,casttype=NodeSelectorOperator"`
    // An array of string values. If the operator is In or NotIn,
    // the values array must be non-empty. If the operator is Exists or DoesNotExist,
    // the values array must be empty. If the operator is Gt or Lt, the values
    // array must have a single element, which will be interpreted as an integer.
    // This array is replaced during a strategic merge patch.
    // +optional
    Values []string `json:"values,omitempty" protobuf:"bytes,3,rep,name=values"`
}
```

And mapping `NodeSelector`:

```
NodeSelector  map[string]string  `json:"nodeSelector,omitempty" protobuf:"bytes,7,rep,name=nodeSelector"`
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I am right or wrong but let's say we have added two different nodes with different labels (disktype=ssd and disktype=hsd).
So if we have a key-value pair then it is easy for us to place a pod on a particular node (for example  diskctype=ssd node).
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/

We can say it is there to separate the nodes and easily select the required node in between two nodes.

example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    env: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  nodeSelector:
    disktype: ssd
```

Please excuse me if I missed something.